# what's the meaning of "Had it up to here"?

Tags: idioms

I saw a sentence "I had it up to here" in [Big Sean's rap lyric](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/bigsean/idontfuckwithyou.html). What does it actually mean?   Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: I can't find that phrase in any Big Sean song through Google. Maybe you misheard or misread?

Comment: The lyric is *had it up to **here***, not *..up to **you***. This idiomatic usage is General Reference.

Comment: You could have made an effort to look the song lyric up yourself and thereby not wasting other people‘s time.

Answer (score 2):

"I've had it up to here" is an idiom meaning "I am fed up with it", "I don't think I can take any more of it" (usually accompanied by a gesture showing at the speaker's neck or over speaker's head).